# Python script to on and off(Show/Hide) any visualization(Cross Table) through Button click

Tags: spotfire

I want to on and off any visualization(Cross Table) through Button click using python script.

So can anyone please help me for this python script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say hide, what are you expecting exactly? what are you trying to accomplish with this? there's not really a functionality to hide panels in spotfire, but you can delete and recreate a visualization programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a bookmark special attached to a button for this. Create two bookmark specials using only the page layout.  One should have the cross table minimized and the other should have it in the position you want.  Then attach those two bookmarks to buttons in a text area.